# WPF: Bind TextBlock Text Value to Selected Button Content in WPF: Pure XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, mvvm

Not sure if this can be done - I've got a WPF Application with a bunch of XAML screens and what I'd like to be able to do on one of them is bind the Text value of a TextBlock to the Content Value of a selected button. I've got say 5 buttons in my XAML and when I click any of them I want the text block to reflect the button content. I know I can do this through Commands ala MVVM but I'd love to do this in pure XAML - no code at all.

Can it be done?

Thanks heaps!

Comment: Code sharing is always a plus

Comment: Add a trigger on your buttons individually or as a template shared by all of them to do a [ChangePropertyAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn195723.aspx) with your `TextBlock` as the TargetObject to its `Text` property with the `Buttons` content and voila, you're done. Answers so short I figured it might as well just be a comment, cheers.

Comment: Set the `Trigger` for your button, in the `<Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding ElementName=(yourElement),Path=(PropertyWithText), RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=(Type of the Container)}}"` HTH, pure xaml solution.

Comment: Of course!! Doh :) Put like that it makes total sense! Thanks loads!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answers below!

Chris W response:

Add a trigger on your buttons individually or as a template shared by all of them to do a ChangePropertyAction with your TextBlock as the TargetObject to its Text property with the Buttons content and voila, you're done.

XAMIMAX response:

Set the Trigger for your button, in the